# How to create a pagination with dynamic currentPage, SurroundingPageCount, Total Items, and Items Per Page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Since yesterday I have been trying to create a pagination with dynamic values, and I keep hitting the wall.

I am using Stencil.js, but it's very similar to React. Both use JSX and JS, but it doesn't matter for this question, since I need the JS logic.

I have 4 dynamic values that users can set on their Pagination component: `total`, `per-page`, `current-page`, and `surrounding-page-count`.
I've done everything except the `surrounding-page-count`.

Here's what I need to happen. If I set `total=50`, `per-page=5`, then I would have 10 page items shown as pagination. If I set `current-page` to be `1` for example, and `surrounding-page-count` to be `2`, then I should see the following: `**[1]**[2][3]...[10]`. If I click on [5], then I should see `[1]...[3][4]**[5]**[6][7]...[10]` etc. You get the point.

I have tried all sorts of ways to achieve this particular functionality, but I struggle with the right logic.

Can somebody please help me figure out how to do it? Remember, I have the `currentPage`, `surroundingPageCount`, `totalPages` and `itemsPerPage`.

Here's a screenshot of how the pagination should look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKM0q.png)

Comment: Could you provide the code you have so far?
Maybe in a online repl or sandbox so we can assist by extending it?

Comment: @LukeStorry This is the relevant function. You won't be able to run it because it's `stencil.js` and some of the variables are Properties. https://jsfiddle.net/y7r9L46x/